# Linux git detached head не знаю как решить

Tags: git

[image: Ввожу команду git checkout и вылезает ошибка]
Не знаю как решить на скрине видно все если что могу отправить то что вводил

Comment: текст в виде текста в вопрос вставьте (с форматированием), а не как картинку, чтобы людям с похожей проблемой легче было ваш вопрос найти, чтобы сделать ответы более полезными¶ Если не знаете как текст из консоли скопировать, задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос, специально об этом.

Comment: git checkout master к чему ведёт?

Comment: А в чём, собственно, проблема? Что вы хотите "решить"? Чем вас не устраивает detached HEAD?

Comment: Я бы скопировал но что-то не додумался я через puTTy подключаюсь

Answer (score 0):

`v1.0.15` - это метка (*tag*), а не ветка (*branch*).

при выполнении `git checkout имя-метки` именно так и должно происходить.

вы получили в рабочем каталоге то содержимое файлов/каталогов, которое и было зафиксировано данной меткой.

---

посмотреть все локальные метки можно командой

```
$ git tag
```

а локальные ветки - командой

```
$ git branch
```

Comment: Я уже вроде как нашел один гайд все шло как по маслу но далее надо было создать коммит я его создавал и далее писало:"Say me who you are" и снизу уже не помню что

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git